# Check if img src contains some string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, indexing

edit, thanks for pointing out the difference between php and js

I'm trying to check if the source of an image contains "upload_pic", and then do stuff. im checking that by indexing the source, but the code doesn't work. Maybe if i can also get a regex workaround too.

```
if ($('#X').attr('src').indexOf("upload_pic") != 0){
alert ('Php Present')
}
```

Comment: If it's a php page then it won't contain php.  It will contain whatever was returned when that php was executed on the server.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  You need to understand the difference between server-side code and client-side code.

Comment: You need to check against -1 not 0 ... <?php could be the first thing in the string (and would therefore would have an index of 0)

Comment: Hah! Orangepill is right. OP is checking to see if the PHP executed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript executes in the browser, and PHP executes on the server.  Because of this relationship, JavaScript is unable to see PHP.

The flow goes like this:

PHP -> HTML -> (over network) -> browser -> JavaScript

In other words, all JavaScript has to work on is the resultant HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Proper, now i get this, i just have to index whatever src is returned by php. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

your way need compare with:

```
index != -1
```

jQuery way:

```
if ( $('#X').is('[src ~= "<?php"]') ) {
    console.log('PHP Present');
}
```

Comment: php will hav been parsed on the server and only html will have been returned.  There will be *no* php tags on the page, anywhere.